# How to remove page margin

Tags: css, navigation

the space is display between page margin and nevigation bar, So how to delete this space

**css code**

```
#topnav ul
{

    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

    overflow:hidden;
}

#topnav li
{   

    float:left;
    display:inline;



}



#topnav a:link,
#topnav a:visited
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:110px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:calibri;

    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#topnav a:hover,
#topnav a:active
{
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

html code

```
<ul id="topnav">
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">OPD</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">IPD</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">Infrastucture</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">Gallery</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">Media</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#contact">Site Map</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#about">Nursing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you provide a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo showing the problem, I will be able to fix it for you.

Answer (score 12):

You need to specifically set margin and padding to 0 on the "body" element.

just try this in your css:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Try using firebug, dragonfly or similar to see which element is having padding or margin. For internet explorer (some version, I think) the html element may also have margin/padding.

Comment: Is the margin to the left of the ul? in that case it might be because of the automatic indentation of li's. try to fiddle with the CSS-property "list-style-position". But really, an demo on JSfiddler would let me solve it in notime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
#topnav { font-size: 0; }
#topnav li { font-size: 12px; } /* or your font size that needed there */
```